# Create a valid regular expression when using input type="date"

Tags: javascript, regex, html, google-chrome, date

I am using a simple date regex to validate an input string is in the desired format:

In this case **`dd/mm/yyyy`**

### THE ISSUE

Regular expression for date validation fails in **Google Chrome** when using **`type="date"`**:

Displays: **dd/mm/yyyy**

Renders: **yyyy-mm-dd** *(Here lies the issue)*

[image: Chrome date issue]

---

### QUESTION

How to use regex *(or alternative)* to validate a date string across browsers when using **`type="date"`**?

**NOTE:** Using regex to validate yyyy-mm-dd is not a valid solution unless the end user still sees dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="date" />` internally handles dates like so:

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Therefore your format should be `^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$`. Note however that you will need to provide clear instruction to users if their browser doesn't support `type="date"`, or provide a JavaScript calendar alternative, otherwise people won't understand!

Due to the current support for `type="date"` being so small, it's probably best to use JavaScript and have a hidden `input` field to store the `YYYY-mm-dd` format date and validate that, while letting the user type freely into the real input field and try to parse that.